# Update values in numpy array without tedious for loops

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a few arrays with data like this:

```
a = np.random.rand(3,3)
b = np.random.rand(3,3)
```

Using for loops I construct larger matrix

```
L = np.zeros((9,9))
for i in range(9):
    for j in range(9):
        L[i,j] = f(a,b,i,j) # values of L depends on values of a and b
```

Later in my program I will change a and b and I want my L array to change too. So the logic of my program looks like this (in pseudo code)

```
Create a
Create b
while True:
    Create L using a and b
    Do the stuff
    Change a
    Change b
```

In my program the size of L is large (10^6 x 10^6 and larger). 
Constructing this L matrix again and again is tedious and slow process.
Instead of doing for loops again and again I would like just to update values of L matrix according to changed values of a and b. The structure of L is the same each time, the only difference is values of cells. Something like this:

```
a[0,0] = 2
b[0,0] = 2
L[3,5] = 2*a[0,0]*b[0,0]
L[3,5]
# >>> 8

a[0,0] = 3
b[0,0] = 1

# do some magic here 
L[3,5]
>>> 6
```

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do.

Comment: The way to avoid loops is to write `f()` in such a way that it works with the whole of `a`, `b`, `np.arange(L)[:,None], and `np.arange(L).  As long as it only works with scalar `i`, `j` values you are stuck with loops.  And without some knowledge of how the values of `L` depend on `a` and `b`, we can't help with the later changes.  Normally we'd just recalculate `L`.

Comment: To update values of L after a and b have changed. I can do it in for loops, but it is slow and inefficient.

Comment: Maybe there is some way to leave like pointers some cells to values in other arrays. Like references. It seems redundant to do the same for loop again and again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can something like this solve your problem ?

```
>>> a = 10
>>> b = 20
>>> def func():
        # fetch the values of a and b
...     return a+b
... 
>>> lis = [func]
>>> lis[0]
<function func at 0x109f70730>
>>> lis[0]()
30
>>> a = 20
>>> lis[0]()
40
```

Basically every time you fetch the value by calling a function
that computes the latest value.